# How is SQL Server creating uniqueidentifier using newid()?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Can anyone please help me out to understand how SQL Server decide which 32 letters in a `Uniqueidentifier` to use when calling `newid()`? My question not to how to crate `uniqueidentifier`, I am trying to understand how internally SQL Server decides this random id, what is the algorithm  used by SQL Server to generate this id.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's an underlying OS call that generates a GUID - SQL Server itself just calls that Windows system function to do this. [See the Wikipedia article on GUID's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs are 16 byte binary values. Displaying them as 32 hexadecimal values is just one representation. They aren't stored as strings of "32 letters"

As documented [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/03/23/newsequentialid-histrorybenefits-and-implementation/)

> The old guid generating function NewId is also a wrapper over an OS
> function CoCreateGuid, therefore all of the semantics of CoCreateGuid
> exist in NewId.

So you'd need to find the implementation of that. But why do you care anyway?